# $(...).DataTable is not a function even after including the js before dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have been trying to integrate a table into my website which pulls data from my database into the table on the website.
I have read all the possible solutions on the internet and couldnt fix the issue yet.

I am putting my code below to have a look.
Please point out where I'm goiing wrong in it and what can i do for it to work.

Otherwise suggest me another option to go for the same function of loading data from the database into the tables inti the HTML site.

The declarations that i have used before the code.

```
      <!--Import jQuery before export.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!--Data Table-->
<script type="text/javascript"  src=" //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src=" //cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table buttons-->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table button CSS-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

This is my HTML code.

```
        <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is my Javascript code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/api/medical_inventory/",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns" : [
                    { "data": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are including jQuery and dataTables 3 different times. Remove the unnecessary ones and it should work fine

Comment: First, off you're including jQuery three times (and three different versions it appears). And datatables is being included twice. All of which can cause weird functionality. Second, try using `jQuery` instead of `$`, or better yet use an IIFE: http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you for providing your inputs.. But i still havent been able to get it up and running.. Do you think i should delete anymore of the jQueries?

Comment: Thank you @eric deleting the extra jQueries worked.

Comment: Thank you @leepowers deleting the extra jQueries worked. I didnt have to use jQuery but i used the method that Rob suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have the ajax call actually return data, and then pass that on to DataTable.  As an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/medical_inventory/",
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $("#myTable").DataTable({
          data: data,
          columns : [
            { title: "Id", className: "myClass" },
            { title: "Name", className: "otherClass" },
          ]
        });
    }
});
```